# Need to solve equations which take vector inputs. I have tried with matlab solve() but I'm getting zeros for both tau_new & b

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations

rc=1;

x=linspace(0,1,1000);

R=exp(1).*x.*rc;

b0=.3614/sqrt(2);

eqn1=(b./(8*pi)).*(1./R).*(log(R./rc)+1)+(b./(2*b0))-tau_new==0,

eqn2=(b./(2*pi)).*(1./R).*(log(R./rc))+(b./(b0))-tau_new==0];

vars=[tau_new b];

[solv, solu] = solve(eqns, vars)

The goal is to have an expression relating tau_new with R i.e. tau_new=f(R) also b=f(R). Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcr}
 \frac{\left(\log \left(\frac{R}{\text{rc}}\right)+1\right) b}{8 \pi  R}+\frac{b}{2 \text{b0}}-\tau &=&0 \\
 \frac{\log \left(\frac{R}{\text{rc}}\right) b}{2 \pi  R}+\frac{b}{\text{b0}}-\tau &=&0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

or

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcr}
G_1(R) b-\tau &=&0 \\
G_2(R)b-\tau &=&0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

or

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
G_1(R) & -1 \\
G_2(R) & -1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
b \\
\tau
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

with $G_1(R) \ne G_2(R)$

so $\det \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
G_1(R) & -1 \\
G_2(R) & -1
\end{array}
\right) = G_2(R)-G_1(R) \ne 0$ and the only solution for this homogeneous system is $b = \tau = 0$